# Force stream events delivery

Tags: testing, dart

I am trying to test stream events in my service, and faced a problem: is any way to synchronously deliver events in async stream? Here is simplified code example:

```
test("deliver event", () {
  StreamController sc = new StreamController();
  String v = "old";
  sc.stream.listen((val) {v = val;});
  sc.add("new");
  expect(v, "new"); // test fails: actual value is "old"
});
```

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make anything from async to sync.

```
import 'dart:async';
Future main() async {
  StreamController sc = new StreamController();
  String v = "old";
  var subscr = sc.stream.listen((val) { v = val;});
  sc.add("new");
  subscr.asFuture().then((_) {
    print('assert v == "new": ${v == 'new'}'); 
    // expect(v, "new"); // test fails: actual value is "old"
  });
  sc.close();
}
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/b1d9f1f4575b54abb315eb10bc1488cc)